# Most similar members in one table

Tags: sql, mariadb

In table `Member_Element`... (InnoDB, mysql via maria db)

```
  Member  Element
  1       A
  1       B
  1       C
  1       E
  2       A
  2       B
  2       C
  2       D
  3       A
  3       D
```

I want to get the Member which have the most common Element with Member 1 (and the % of silimiltude.) Member 2 have A,B,C in common with Member 1 and should be the "winner" because Member 3 have only A in common.

What I have is:

```
SELECT Member,Element
FROM Member_Element
WHERE Member=1 
 AND Element IN (SELECT Element
                 FROM Member_Element
                 GROUP BY Element
                 HAVING count(*)>1)
```

which gives: Element A,B,C ... and wished result set would be : 2 (Member 2)

I guess I need help for the next step and putting all subquery together.

I saw "SQL- Selecting the most similar product", but it's too complicate for my understanding and need.

Comment: The error: If you use an IN clause, the number of field in que subquery must be 1, you have write Member, Element

Comment: Please, give use further information, as the result set you wished

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Can you expand on this line *I want to get the Member which have the most common Element with Member 1 (and the % of silimiltude.)*

Comment: @Joe Taras : i puted a "fixed" code. Tanks.

Comment: @StefG: Dear, as you have posted your data set (list of couple Member / Element), post your wished result set, so we can help better

Comment: Being a C coder, can someone put/tell variables, like the type of the subquery result, or any others that would put c&friends light on sql language? A kind of table[qty of selected elements] ?_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use a simple join?

```
SELECT a.member, count(a.member) as total 
FROM t1 a JOIN t1 b 
WHERE a.element=b.element AND b.member=1 AND a.member > 1 
GROUP BY a.member ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: By Odin's beard what trickery is that! Wow tank you! So JOIN on 1 table creat a 2nd kind of virtual/copy table?... (nice trick!). And GROUP BY create a kind of sub-table divided in a.member on the select+where result?...